# python __getattr__ get multiple value get

Tags: python-3.x, getattr

python class module `__getattr__` use funation `obj.val1.val2` error. python program for.

```
class hub:
    def __getattr__(self,__name):
        print(__name)

obj = hub()
obj.val1.val2
```

error:

```
val1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hub.py", line 6, in <module>
    obj.val1.val2
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val2'
```

Expert Value:

```
val1.val2
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute obj.val1 is none. When you use obj.val1.val2 it actually calls the **getattr** of obj.val1 which is none. Because obj.val1 is none and doesn't have a val2 attribute you receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning anything which is equivalent to returning None and then you are trying to get another attribute from none which fails.

this code should works if you are just trying to print the values:

```
class hub:
    def __getattr__(self,__name):
        print(__name)
        return self

obj = hub()
obj.val1.val2
```

otherwise if you are trying to get a tuple of value you are trying to do it the wrong way it will not work with `__getattr__` directly.
use `__getitem__` first

```
class hub:
    def __getitem__(self, *keys):
        return [self.__getattr__(k) for k in keys]

    def __getattr__(self,__name):
        # get the item here and return it

obj = hub()
obj["val1", "val2"]
```

Comment: expert value for `val1.val2`. but not print this code